# Show a set is sigma-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f \in {\cal L}^{1}(X,M,\mu)$, show that $\{x \in X: f(x) \not = 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite

Here is my attempt: for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, define $S_k := \{x \in X: |f(x)| > \frac{1}{k}\}$, then $\bigcup_{k} S_k = \{x \in X : f(x) \not = 0\}$, but how to show that $\mu(S_k) < \infty$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

My thinking is : $\infty > \int_X |f| d\mu \ge \int_X |f| \chi_{S_k}d\mu > \frac{1}{k} \int_X \chi_{S_k}d\mu = \frac{1}{k} \mu(S_k)$, is it right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds $$\int_X |f| d\mu \ge \int_{S_k} |f| d\mu \ge \frac{1}{k}\mu(S_k)$$ hence if $\mu(S_k) = \infty$ for some $k$ you get the contradiction $f\not\in \mathcal{L}^1$

Answer (score 0):

This is Markov's inequality,
$$ \mu(S_k) ≤ \int_{|f|>1/k} k|f|  ≤ k\int_X |f| = k\| f\|_{L^1} < \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu(S_k)=\infty$ then $\int|f|d\mu\geq\frac1{k}\mu(S_k)=\infty$ contradicting that $f \in {\cal L}^{1}(X,M,\mu)$